# How to return both row and column of all instances of a value in a table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a similar issue solved in another post -- [How to return row based on all searched instances of a value in a Table excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148516/how-to-return-row-based-on-all-searched-instances-of-a-value-in-a-table-excel?newreg=8412059479e1487e92b2c0671f709fa5) with some additional challenges.

I'm creating an executive summary of a different sheet identifying items that have changed, and identifying the nature of the change.

The first row has a list of unique IDs and the different column headings contain different parameters. This larger data set is on a sheet named "Changes from Prior Issuance".

[image: Snapshot of the sheet]

The first formula should return the ID of every item that contains any instance of "DELTA" and the second should identify the parameter that's changed.

So the in the example, the first function would return C440 and the second would return panel type.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Good practice is to show to the community what you try. In your question, there are some things that still are not clear: Can Delta be located anywhere? Can Delta be repeated? How/where you want to get those data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these formulas

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$8)/($B$1:$G$8="DELTA"),COLUMN(A1))),"")

=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$G$1,,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B$1:$G$1)/($B$1:$G$8="DELTA"),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

which should work for the example in your picture. The formula can be pulled sideways to show all occurences. If you want to pull it downwards just change `COLUMN(A1)` to `ROW(A1)`.

[image]